# DAGs: instrumental and adjusted variables

Tags: regression, causality, instrumental-variables, dag, causal-diagram

While drawing DAGs, we can define variables as exposure, outcome and unobserved etc. Could you please explain, what are instrumental and adjusted variables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> While drawing DAGs...what are instrumental and adjusted variables?

An instrumental variable is an observed variable that is often used to help obtain an unbiased estimate for a causal effect that is confounded by another variable that is usually unobserved. The classical situation can be depicted in the following DAG:

[image]

Here, **X** is our main exposure, and the causal effect of **X** on **Y** is confounded by **U**. **Z** is an instrumental variable for **X**: it is associated with **X** (and unconfounded) but not with **Y**; affects **Y** only via **X**; and both **Z** and **Y** have no common causes.

An adjusted variable is simply an observed variable which is adjusted for (ie. included as a covariate) in a regression model.